# Mirth Write to SFTP server Error

Tags: javascript, mirth

I am having a hard time writing my file to a SFTP server. When I use the channel.put(fileBody) I get the error Wrapped 5: Bad message and when I try to use FilesUtil.write I get that it is not define. 
Any help would be great.

```
var channel = session.openChannel('sftp');
channel.connect();


channel.cd("/test");
//channel.put(connectorMessage.getRawData());
var filename = $('FileName');
var filebody = connectorMessage.getRawData();
channel.put(filebody);

//FilesUtil.write(filename, filebody);
```